# How do I compare an Arc<T> against a T?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I'm trying to treat `Arc` more like its underlying data, in particular I'm trying to use overloaded operators.  The following code **gives errors** but was my attempt.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::option::Option;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub struct SomeNum {
    num: u32,
}

impl std::cmp::PartialEq<u32> for SomeNum {
    fn eq(&self, other: &u32) -> bool {
        return *other == self.num;
    }
}

impl std::cmp::PartialOrd<u32> for SomeNum {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &u32) -> Option<Ordering> {
        if (self.num < *other) {
            return Option::Some(Ordering::Less);
        }
        if (self.num > *other) {
            return Option::Some(Ordering::Greater);
        }
        return Option::Some(Ordering::Equal);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test_num = SomeNum { num: 16 };
    let oveloadedNum = test_num > 10; // works

    let arc_num = Arc::new(test_num);
    let overloadedArc = arc_num > 10; // fails

    let arc_num_clone = Arc::clone(&arc_num);
    let overloadedArcClone = arc_num_clone > 10; // fails
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=734793f3656588dd941ea4b070caf1c0)

I tried using `impl Arc<SomeNum>` but you can't do that for things outside of your crate.  Beyond this, I'm very very new to Rust (day 2), so I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  Perhaps I could extend `Arc`, then implement stuff for it?

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: What about generics?  I tried `SCREAMING_SNAKE` and my linter got upset.

Comment: Generics count as types, but are usually single letters. Otherwise, they are short so as to be unlikely to collide with a concrete type name: `Ty` or `Col`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Arc` can be used as `SomeNum` because it is dereferenced whenever you call a function on it. If you have a look at the [documentation of `Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#deref-behavior), you will see that dereferencing `Arc<T>` results in a `T`.

You have implemented `PartialOrd` and `PartialEq` only for the struct `SomeNum`, so `>` will only work with `SomeNum`. You have to dereference your `Arc`s before comparing them.

```rust
fn main() {
    let test_num = SomeNum { num: 16 };
    let oveloadedNum = test_num > 10; // works

    let arc_num = Arc::new(test_num);
    let overloadedArc = *arc_num > 10;

    let arc_num_clone = Arc::clone(&arc_num);
    let overloadedArcClone = *arc_num_clone > 10;
}
```